# Cсылочная арифметика в GNU C

Tags: c, gnu

Ссылочная арифметика С странно работает. Я провел два простых эксперимента и оказалось,что не вычисляются:

```
a = b->c->c->...
a = &((*b)->c);
```

Декларации одного имени типа как struct T и T суть разные типы и вызывают конфликт. Это так и должно быть или у меня компилятор дефектный?

gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)

typedef struct Ts * Tp;
typedef struct {
    struct Tp c;
} Ts;

Ts c = {NULL};      /*1-!*/
Ts b = {&c};        /*2-!*/
Ts a = {&b};        /*3-!*/
Tp d = &a;          /*4-!*/

int main(void) 
{
    Tp e = d->c->c->c;  /*5-?*/
    Tp * f = &d;        /*6-!*/
    f = &((*f)->c);     /*7-?*/
    f = &a.c;           /*8-!*/
    *f = (*f)->c;       /*9-?*/
    return 0;
}
```

И без декларации указателя - еще хуже:

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)

typedef struct {
    struct T * c;
} T;

T c = {NULL};   /*1-!*/
T b = {&c};     /*2-?*/
T a = {&b};     /*3-?*/
T * d = &a;     /*4-!*/

int main(void) {
    T * e = d->c->c->c; /*5-?*/
    T ** f = &d;        /*6-!*/
    f = &((*f)->c);     /*7-?*/
    f = &a.c;           /*8-?*/
    *f = (*f)->c;       /*9-?*/
    return 0;
}
```

Знаком вопроса отмечены строки с ошибками или предупреждениями.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Адресная арифметика в С работает корректно. У Вас какой вопрос ?

Comment: Ну, в первом варианте `struct Ts` вообще не объявлена. Возможно Вы хотели написать -- `
typedef struct Ts * Tp;
typedef struct Ts {
    Tp c;
} Ts;` ? Только от  таких `typedef`-ов код понятней не станет.

Comment: А что вообще запрограммировать желаете?

Comment: Я с С работал не много. **Как же правильно объявить рекуррентную ссылку в структуре, без лишних именований?** Если тип есть структура то почему нужно писать этот struct везде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хотите заменить

```
typedef struct {
    struct T * c;
} T;
```

на

```
typedef struct U {
    struct U * c;
} T;
```

?

Comment: Я конечно так не советую делать но запись вида `typedef struct T * T;
struct T { struct T * T; };  .... T T = {0};  .. T->T ` корректна

Comment: Объявив 
**typedef struct S {
 struct S * c;
} T;**
второй пример заработал, все кроме пятого выражения. Но это не логично, какй же тип у структуры S или T? К чему это многсловие?

Comment: @Вячеслав: У этой структуры тип `struct S`. Вы для этого типа еще завели короткий псевдоним `T`. Зачем - надо у вас спрашивать. Сделали бы `typedef struct S { struct S * c; } S;` и пользовались бы на здоровье коротким именем `S`. Зачем было придумывать новое имя `T`?

Comment: Двойственность объявления типа структуры есть только в С. T не псевдоним а имя типа почему то несовместного с S. При применении T к переменным, в программе, указывать struct не обязательно, в отличии от S. Вы правы лишние символы вредны.

Answer (score 2):

> Декларации одного имени типа как struct T и T суть разные типы и вызывают конфликт.

Разумеется. Так всегда было в языке С.

Ваша расстановка знаков вопроса тоже вызывает сомнения. В первом примере объявление поля `struct Tp c;` - уже ошибка, ибо типа `struct Tp` в программе не определено, а объявлять поля неполных типов в языке С запрещается. Дальше можно не смотреть, и зачем вы ставили какие-то знаки вопроса в этом коде - не ясно.

Во втором примере имеют место банальные несоответствия типов между беcтаговым struct типом с typedef-псевдонимом `T` и никакого отношения к нему не имеющим неопределенным таговым типом `struct T`.

Comment: В реальном компиляторе, объявление типа структуры как `typedef struct T {struct T * t; ...} T;` разрешило все проблемы с несовместимостью типов и рекурентностью. В первом примере объявление `struct` перед `Tp c;` ошибочное, вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

Объявить рекуррентную ссылку в структуре возможно так:

```
typedef struct T {
     struct T * c;
} T;
```

Многословно, но только так все работает. Спасибо, Yaroslav.

Comment: Ну не обязательно это делать *именно* так. Альтернативный вариант того же: `typedef struct T T; struct T { T *c; };`. По многословности не отличается, но в ряде случаев это может быть лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Я кажется понял в чем Вопрос. Вы хотите использовать переопределение структуре при инициализации структуры. Ваша запись

```
typedef struct T
{
  struct T T;
} T;
```

Эквивалентна записи

```
struct T
{
  struct T T;
};
typedef strcut T T;
```

Но переопределение может быть до объявления структуры, поэтому можно записать так.

```
typedef struct T T;
struct T
{
  T * T;
};
```

Но Я оформляю такую конструкцию вот так

```
typedef struct _name_s name_s;
struct _name_s
{
  name_s * name;
};
```

Comment: Да, вы правы, эта путаница со структурами и типами характерна только для С. Так сложилось, структуры были в С еще до введения системы типов и **typedef**.